# React Context Provider override not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context

#### The Goal

Hello

I have a React project with NextJS where I want to chose whether using light or dark theme depending on the background / section.

#### My solution

I have found that the best solution to my problem is using React Context API. To change the theme I just need to override the provider with a new one ([as indicated in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)).

#### The problem

I have the start of a solution but when overriding the Provider, I noticed that the change isn't effective for every components even if in the devTools the context in theses components is the correct one.

I have tried switching from `useContext(context)` to `<context.Consumer>` but there was no improvement.

#### The code:

*/context/Theme*

```tsx
import { createContext, JSXElementConstructor, ReactElement, ReactFragment, ReactNode, ReactPortal } from "react";
import { getTheme, Theme } from "../constants/theme";

// type of getTheme: (theme: 'light' | 'dark') => Theme

const ThemeContext = createContext<Theme>(getTheme('light'))

export default ThemeContext

interface ThemeProviderProps {
    theme: 'light' | 'dark'
    children: string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | null | undefined
}

interface ThemeConsumerProps {
    children: (value: Theme) => ReactNode
}

// The goal here is to make the theme switching more natural
export const ThemeProvider = (props: ThemeProviderProps): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={getTheme(props.theme)}>
            {props.children}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
}

// Just for convenience
export const ThemeConsumer = (props: ThemeConsumerProps): JSX.Element => {
    return <ThemeContext.Consumer>{props.children}</ThemeContext.Consumer>
}
```

*/pages/_app* (Starting point of NextJS App, equivalent to */src/App*

```tsx
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

import { ThemeProvider } from "../context/Theme";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme="light">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

*/common/Popup/Popup*

```tsx
import {ReactNode, useContext, useState} from "react";
import styles from "./Popup.module.css"

import Typography, {Typos} from "../Typography";
import Icon from "../Icon";

import {CloseIcon} from "../../icons";
import ThemeContext, {ThemeProvider, ThemeConsumer} from "../../context/Theme";

interface Props {
    children: ReactNode
    title: string
    open: boolean
    close: () => void
}

export default function (props: Props): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <>
            // ...
            <ThemeProvider theme="dark">
                <div className={styles.header}>
                    <Typography level={Typos.TITLE_2} bold>{ props.title }</Typography>  // The useContext works inside of this components
                    <ThemeConsumer>
                        {(theme) =>
                            <Icon icon={CloseIcon} color={theme.texts.secondary} size={1.5}
                                  onClick={props.close} clickable />
                        }
                    </ThemeConsumer>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.body}>
                    { props.children }  // The useContext or the <context.Consumer> doesn't work for the children
                </div>
            </ThemeProvider>
            // ...
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just misplaced my `<context.Consumer>` outside of the Popup component and I learned that `useContext` doesn't work when overriding the Provider.

Comment: Hey! I know it's been a long time since your answer, but I'm wondering what do you mean by "useContext doesn't work when overriding the Provider"? 

I'm having trouble to override Context down the App router tree.

Thanks!